# How to work with OnChange Submit & Form Target to iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload

I'm having a slight problem.

I have set my `<input type="file">` to `onChange="this.form.submit()"`.

The file selector will fire the submit, but if I have my `<form>` element targeted to an iFrame, the browser will return a Popup blocked error and will stop the submit!

The `.submit()` works fine without a target specified - but as soon as I have a target, it'll block it!

Is there a work around for this?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the HTML:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" title="uploader_iframe" id="uploader_iframe" style="display:block;"></iframe>
<form target="uploader_iframe" action="upload.php" id="the_form" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" id="beta_uploader" size="1" onchange="document.forms['the_form'].submit()" name="file" /></form>
```

Also, the validate() function does not get called :S

Comment: I switched form() and submit for you. Can you post the form tag too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

Forgot to Specifiy the iFrame with the tag `<iframe NAME="uploader_iframe">`